Splitting string with three parts into two when only separated by spaces - Bigquery
I am creating a database of names in BigQuery. The source data provides the name in this format: last first middle (aka, no commas, only spaces).
What I want to end up with is last, first middle (essentially inserting a comma after the last name).
At first, I thought I'd need to do a REGEXP_EXTRACT after the first space.
Essentially:
CONCAT(SPLIT(REGEXP_EXTRACT(Teacher_Name, r'^[^ ]*'),' ')) AS Teacher_Name

...but that's not working as I get the error "Query error: Grouping by expressions of type ARRAY is not allowed at [21:25]".

There is no SPLIT function needed.
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(Teacher_Name, r'[^ ]*$') ||', ' || REGEXP_EXTRACT(Teacher_Name, r'^[^ ]*') as Teacher_Name
FROM unnest(['Ana J Hope','Thomas Hope','this is no name']) as Teacher_Name

Please consider using a JavaScript UDF, because it has a more powerful regex syntax and enables to fix upper and lower cases. Also a sanity check could be included.

Consider below approach
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION PICK_PARTS(text STRING) AS ((
  SELECT TRIM(STRING(ml_generate_text_result['predictions'][0]['content']), '" ')
  FROM ML.GENERATE_TEXT(MODEL `your_project.your_dataset.your_model_llm`,
  (SELECT 'for text ' || text || ' - extract first name, middle name and last name and output in following format: last name, first name middle name.' AS prompt )
)));                                        
SELECT fullname, PICK_PARTS(fullname) formatted_fullname
FROM sample_data    

If apply to sample data like below
WITH sample_data AS (
  SELECT 'Jane Doe' AS fullname UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Emily R. Johnson' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Marco Antonio Silva' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Anika Priya Desai' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'François Pierre de la Varenne' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ludwig Wolfgang Schmidt' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Berlyant Mikhail' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Alejandra Consuelo Castillo Reyes' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Dmitri Aleksandrovich Ivanov' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Nelson Rolihlahla Mandela' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Malala Yousafzai' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mikhail Sergeyevich Gorbachev' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Barack Hussein Obama II' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Angela Dorothea Merkel' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Indira Priyadarshini Gandhi' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Aung San Suu Kyi' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ban Ki-moon' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Frida Kahlo de Rivera' UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'Charlotte Amelia Elizabeth Wentworth-Fitzwilliam' 
) 

output is

See details on how to use ML.GENERATE_TEXT function
Just to better understand what is going on above  - it is equivalent to as if you do similar request to your favorite AI Assistant - like in below example

